# Given sets $A,B$, there exists injection $f:A\to B$ or injection $g:B\to A$

Tags: functions, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

The claim in the title is pretty obvious when choice is assumed (Apply Zorn's lemma to the subset of the powerset of $A$ of subsets of $A$ which allow injections to $B$. Consider a maximal element and construct an injection backwards if the maximal element isn't $A$)

Is it possible to show this without choice? If not, what is the weakest form of choice we need to assume?

Comment: I think the last proposition in http://math.andrej.com/2009/09/08/constructive-stone-cardinality-of-sets/ yields that a fully constructive proof is impossible. (Please check.)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/268942